# Simple object retrieval from CouchDB in Scala

Tags: scala, couchdb

I'm Scala/CouchDB newbie with a simple use case. I need to store some Scala case class instances into the CouchDB. The data in the instances are "almost" static (update happens only during my service restart).

All I need is:

1. Insert the instance to CouchDB
2. Get the instance from CouchDB

I'm trying to use Scouchdb (https://github.com/debasishg/scouchdb).

- I can use sjson for object
  serialization, but I would expect
  scouchdb to do it on its own.
- I know
  about by_id(id) and get(id) method for
  retrieval, but I'm kinda not able to
  figure it out - it seems all examples are out of date

Can anyone give me simple example (if such exists) how to achieve my goal?

And last but not least, is there any relation between dispatch-couch and scouchdb?

Thanks

Comment: 'scouchdb' tag could be probably useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods I needed are found on Db class

For inserting:

```
/** create a doc from an object with auto id generation */
def doc[T <: AnyRef](obj: T)
```

For retrieval there is:

```
/** get an entity of type <tt>T</tt> based on its id. Returns a
Tuple3 of (id, ref, T) */
def get[T](id: String)
```

See https://github.com/debasishg/scouchdb/blob/master/src/main/scala/scouch/db/Database.scala